# Can I use rsync to replace newer files with older files?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, rsync, cp

Assume the following:

```
source:
- foo    3/1/2021
- bar    2/1/2021
- foobar 1/1/2021

destination:
- foo    1/1/2021
- bar    2/1/2021
- foobar 3/1/2021
```

Suppose I want rsync to replace newer files with older ones, like this:

```
source:
- foo    3/1/2021 // Newer
- bar    2/1/2021 // Same age
- foobar 1/1/2021 // Older

destination:
- foo    1/1/2021 // unchanged
- bar    2/1/2021 // unchanged
- foobar 1/1/2021 // overwritten because it was newer than the source.
```

How can I do this? The reverse is possible with `--update`.

Comment: The standard rsync behaviour (incl with -a) is to replace any files on destination that differ from the source, regardless of whether newer or older i.e. including replacing newer with older. Do you really want something else?

Comment: @gogoud Yes. It doesnt have to be with RSync neccessarily but ideally it should.